# timestamp between date range

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to find all record count for each day using query:

```
select cast(Timestamp_field as date), count(*) as cnt
from table1 
group by 1 
having cast(Timestamp_field as date) between date and date -10;
```

`Timestamp_field` is a timestamp and I am casting this to date. This; despite max value of Timestamp_field showing `2016-09-20 12:31:38.000000`, doesn't return any record. Any idea why?

Comment: Btw, when you Explain your query you will notice *unsatisfiable condition*, i.e. optimizer knows that this WHERE results in no rows :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is the `between`.  Perhaps this will work for you:

```
select cast(Timestamp_field as date), count(*)
from table1
group by 1
having cast(Timestamp_field as date) between date - 10 and date;
```

The smaller value should go first for the between comparands.

Note:  You should do the filtering *before* the `group by`, not after:

```
select cast(Timestamp_field as date), count(*)
from table1
where cast(Timestamp_field as date) between date - 10 and date;
group by 1
```